# Behavior at infinity.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, analyticity, laurent-series

> Classify the behavior at $\infty$ for $$f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z^2},\,g(z)=\frac{1}{\sin z},\,h(z)=\exp\left(\tan\frac{1}{z}\right).$$

So I just considered $f(1/z),g(1/z),h(1/z)$ at $z=0$. For $f$ I get $z=0$ as an essential singularity, but I'm not sure about $g$ and $h$. Also I'm stuck on evaluating $\lim_{z\to0}f(1/z),g(1/z),h(1/z)$ (so I can classify the behaviors at infinity). If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{x\to0}f(1/x)=0$.

Comment: Do you look for the limits of this functions?

Comment: limit as z goes to 0 of f(1/z), g(1/z), h(1/z)

Comment: also classify the singularities at 0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $z \in \mathbb{R}$, \sin{z} is bounded $\forall z \in \mathbb{R}$.  Therefore

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin{z}}{z^2} = 0$$

$1/\sin{z}$, on the other hand, varies between $1$ and $\infty$ $\forall z \in \mathbb{R}$.  Therefore this limit is undefined.

Because $\exp{(\tan{z})}$ is uniformly continuous, its limit as $z\rightarrow 0$ is $\exp{(0)} = 1$.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure $z\in\mathbb{C}$ since it's complex analysis.